# invalid configuration 'sw٦٠٠dp-v13'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am trying to build a flutter app from exiting project but I get the following:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        D:\dev\mobile\fluxstore\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-sw٦٠٠dp-v13\values-sw٦٠٠dp-v13.xml: error: invalid configuration 'sw٦٠٠dp-v13'.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        D:\dev\mobile\fluxstore\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-h٧٢٠dp-v13\values-h٧٢٠dp-v13.xml: error: invalid configuration 'h٧٢٠dp-v13'.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 34s
```

I searched too much about this error but it didn't help

Comment: Probably you need to modify the file name `values-sw٦٠٠dp-v13.xml` to `values-sw600dp-v13.xml`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work out

Comment: Also change the outer folder names as `values-sw٦٠٠dp-v13` to `values-sw600dp-v13`

Comment: I see that in the log you have many of them like `values-h٧٢٠dp-v13`; you should have only English numbers on these files; please modify them all inside `\res\values\` and check all sub-directories

Comment: I think thats because my windows language isn't English I will change it now and try

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error, change your windows language to English